# Tensorflow: Preparing input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to replicate a deep neural network from a research paper. The architecture can be found here:

[image]

I have completed designing the model, and now I am attempting to prepare training data. I have been using the tensorflow tutorials found here as a guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

In the case of the mnist data, a 27x27 image is converted to a 1d vector for x. On the other hand, y_ has the shape [none, 10] because each image has the possibility to labeled 10 different ways (0-9)

```
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
 y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
```

My data is a 32x32x7 3d image so x is easy to calculate.

```
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 7168])
```

**Although my image is 32x32x7, each pixel has a density and label associated with it**. I believe the density values will be loaded into x and the labels would be loaded into y. Is this a correct assumption or should I be loading my data in a different way?

```
 y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 7168])
```

Comment: You're right: Insofar that the problem you are trying to solve is the determination of a label for a given image, including density, then the moment you one-hot encode your labels, the dimension of the dimension of the response variable will be the number of labels (so probably less than 7168).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my image is 32x32x7, each pixel has a density and label associated with it

If so, then the output of the network, and the target `y_`, would be of shape:

```py
[
 None,         # Batch size
 32 * 32 * 7,  # Vector size
 N             # N target labels (one hot encoded)
]
```

Comment: Also, with the solution you provided, does this mean that each input image will only have one label? I was under the impression each input image would get 7168 labels (one label for each pixel)

Comment: @DevinHaslam Each pixel can have `N` possible labels. `y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.tensordot(x, W, axes=[[1], [1]]) + L)` with `W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros[7168, 7168, 10])` and `L = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7168, 10]))`.

Comment: unfortunately I get an error after line "W = ..." saying 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @DevinHaslam `W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7168, 7168, 10]))`

Comment: Last question: now that I have made these adjustments, how do I read in the label data to an array of that shape. Currently I do this:
    b = np.zeros((1,7168), dtype = int)
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: a, y_: b})

Comment: @DevinHaslam It'll depend on how your loss function is defined. The `b` you are using should work if each element `i` of `b` contains an index saying which label the `i`th pixel has. However, depending on the loss function definition, you may need to make it into an one-hot encoded vector.

Comment: I guess due to my loss function, b needs to be the same shape as y_. Therefore, what I have for b is incorrect. making b = np.zeros((1,7168,N), dtype = int) works, but then I dont understand how I would feed my label data into b since there are now 7168*N positions in the array. Could you possibly give an example for how I would make the one-hot encoded vector?